# Silverlight Data Access - how to keep the gruntwork on the server

Tags: silverlight, jboss

What technologies are used / recommended for HTTP Rpc Calls from Silverlight.  My Server Side stack is JBoss (servlets / json_rpc [jabsorb]), and we have a ton of business logic (object creation, validation, persistence, server side events) in place that I still want to take advantage of.

This is our first attempt at bringing an applet style ria to our product, and ideally we keep both HTML and Silverlight versions.

For better or worse the powers that be have pushed us down the silverlight path, and while flex / java fx / silverlight is an interesting debate, that question is removed from the equation.  We just have to find a way to get silverlight to behave with our classes.

Should I be defining .NET Class representation of our JSON objects and the methodology to serialize / deserialize access to those objects?  IE "blah.com/dispenseRpc?servlet=xxxx&p1=blah&p2=blahblah creating functions that invoke the web request and convert the incomming response string to objects?

Another way would be to reverse engineer the .NET wcf(or whatever) communications and implement the handler on the Java side that invokes the correct server side code and returns what .NET expects back.  But that sounds much trickier.

T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well since we are using JSON Rpc over HTTP on the server -> HTML clients, we decided to use HTTP calls and  the .NET JsonSerializer; future plans are to add Java Annotations on our EJB project and a console applciation that will run against the EJB and generate the HTTP calls and F# Records with the DataContract attributes.

It is working pretty smoothly. Had some issues with async in silverlight, but got it working with some aid from the folks at MS.

Thx